# How to line up two audio tracks in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere, editing, audio

I understand that I'm down to the frame size on the timeline scale but I need to line these up, otherwise it sounds completely ridiculous. I can't move the two closer together since one overshoots the line-up.

1. What is the best "bandaid" fix for now?
2. How can I avoid this problem later? I record audio on two different mics, I need to be able to perfectly line them up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Audio in Premiere can be aligned by analysing two or more audio files and automatically comparing for similarity.

For the audio recorded on separate microphones, select both clips, right-click and select 'Synchronise'. Select 'Audio' as a synchronize point and press OK.

[image]

You can use the Source editor to fine-tune the in and out points to remove any silence before and after the microphone recording.

[image]

This feature can be extremely useful for aligning multi-cam footage.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to find a band-aid quicky fix. The desired audio/video tracks to be synchronized must be unlinked and only one audio track has to be moved separately, then you can match it up to milliseconds. Now, in my case, I make commentary over a video, so my commentary will be simply early or late, depending which track you move, but only by about a frame, which is not a big deal for me - as long as the audio and video are synchronized. If you're making a song or something very "flowy", this will probably not be helpful.